# Set ID for each div from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hey guys here is an example of what i am trying to do :

```
   const array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
    const divsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".myDiv");
    const changeDivId = (arr) => {
        arr.forEach((element, index) => {
            divsArray[index].id = element;
        });
    };

    changeDivId(array);
   return (
        <div className="myDiv">
...
```

Long story short i am trying to pass an ID from my `array` from above to each one of my div's. But it seems that i have an error of `id` of undefined . What am i doing wrong ? Can someone give me a hand ?
The final result that i am expecting to see is :

```
<div className="myDiv" id="1" />
<div className="myDiv" id="2" />
<div className="myDiv" id="3" />
<div className="myDiv" id="4" />
<div className="myDiv" id="5" />
...
```

Comment: Are you doing something with the IDs later? Dynamically indexed IDs are exceedingly strange and should be avoided in most cases. If you have more context around what functionality you're trying to accomplish here, can you post it?

Comment: Also, is this react? Looks like jsx `return (<div className="myDiv">`

Comment: @Aalexander Pretty sure he's using React, see the JSX in the `return` and his profile

Comment: Are you using any framework? "returning" a div on your function looks like JSX. Dynamic properties differ from framework to framework.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes i am using React . The thing is that i have a set of checkboxes . And i need to add some additional ID's . So i thought why not wrapping them with a div and setting ID's on it

Comment: Why do you need to "add some additional IDs"? Can you elaborate on how that helps you achieve the functionality you're trying to implement?

Comment: Why not add the ids this while rendering those divs?

Comment: @PandaMastr wasn't my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using React.

You shouldn't manually edit the DOM in JSX (which is the underlying markup syntax of React) because of how the virtual DOM works.

If you change an `id` using a `querySelector`, you will only be changing the DOM, but the virtual DOM remains unchanged.

Therefore, next time React re-renders, your DOM update will not be there.

This is why you should do it using JSX propper syntax:

```
const ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

return (
  <>
    {ids.map(id => {
      return <div id={id} key={id}></div>
    })}
  </>
)
```

*And just on a side note, you know you probably shouldn't use 1, 2, 3 as ids, right? They should be UNIQUE on the page.*